# Closing a database link in .NET, ORA-02080

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I have some code that uses a database link that needs to be closed when it's done with.
I call `DBMS_SESSION.Close_database_link` but it gives me the error, ORA-02080, even though the link is no longer in use.

When I tried it in SQL*Plus, it worked great and closed after I ran `COMMIT`.  But in .Net, even if I run commit it doesn't close.

```
using (var con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(@"Data Source=firefly8;User Id=USER;Password=PWD;Pooling=false;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                var c = con.CreateCommand();
                c.CommandText = "select a from tnoam@link_2";
                using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    r.Read();
                }
                c.Dispose();

                var c2 = con.CreateCommand();
                c2.CommandText = "begin commit; dbms_session.close_database_link ('link_2');end;";

                c2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I'm pretty stuck with this one. Please Help

Based on the comment from @Ben I tried the following, it didn't work as well:

```
    using (var con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(@"Data Source=firefly8;User Id=MILK_NEW;Password=MILK_NEW;Pooling=false;"))
{
    con.Open();
    var t = con.BeginTransaction();
    var c = con.CreateCommand();
    c.Transaction = t;
    c.CommandText = "select a from tnoam@link_2";
    using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
    {
        r.Read();
    }
    t.Commit();
    c.Dispose();

    var c2 = con.CreateCommand();
    c2.CommandText = "begin commit; dbms_session.close_database_link ('link_2');end;";

    c2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I find it very strange that you're closing the command `OracleCommand` object before committing the transaction. I can't find anything that explicitly says you shouldn't but I would swap these around. Also, you should probably be using the stored procedure objects rather than creating an anonymous block.

Comment: Sorry about that, the transaction bit is redundant. I removed it.

Comment: it's not redundant. As you noted you have to `commit` or `rollback`.

Comment: I never started a transaction.
I tried it also with a transaction, and a commit before the close database link - it didn't work.
Here is what I also tried:
I added the second try to the original question

Comment: Performing any DML operation in Oracle automatically starts a transaction unless, I suppose, your connection is in auto-commit mode.

Comment: @BobJarvis I didn't do any dml

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/ora-02080-database-link-is-in-use.html.  The only suggestion this article has is to disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: Thanks guys, you sent me in the right direction and I solved it. See answer below

Comment: SELECT is a DML statement.  DML = Data Manipulation Language = part of SQL.  Other DML statements include UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT.  The converse, sort of, is DDL = Data Definition Language = the part of SQL concerned with creating, deleting, and modifying thingssuch as tables, views, procedures, etc.  DML is pretty much standardized, although each product has its own extensions.  DDL is very much NOT standardized, and each product has its own DDL statements.

Comment: @BobJarvis as I understood, SQL is for Query, DML is manipulation (update, insert, delete) and DDL is structure (Create Table etc...)

Comment: I realize this may be a bit of overkill, but failure to tilt at windmills such as this might mean I'd lose my DonQuixotic badge.  :-)  For definitions of DML and DDL in an Oracle context, as well as DCL and TCL (which I'd never heard before - learned some new ones today!) see [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967403/closing-a-database-link-in-net-ora-02080#comment14322545_10967403), I got on my way and found the solution.

It seems that by default Oracle caches cursors and keeps them open. And if the cursor is open, you can't close the database link.

The flag in the connection string that controls the cursor cache is:

```
Statement Cache Size
```

You can manually clear the cache by calling the `PurgeStatementCache` cache method of the [OracleConnection class](http://docs.Oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleConnectionClass.htm)